# post variable problem

Tags: php

I'm working on a web site which creates images online ... there is an SWF which sends variables via post to PHP, and it works fine on my PC but when I test on the server, there are missing variables, specifically the one which contains the colour of the pixels in the image (biggest image is 77 kb). I have set up `post_max_size = 32M`

Any clue what the problem might be?

Comment: Can you provide some code and var_dump() results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some security enforced on PHP to block binary data in POST variables (Suhosin, mod_security, etc.).

Comment: i think the problem came from 
suhosin.post.max_value_length = 65000
my tab is 140000 but after i changed suhosin.ini no thing changed it sitll 65000 
how do i have to proceed

Comment: there is lot of suhisin settings which migth influence this, check logs for problems it is reporting and increase corresponding limit

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Michal. Sometimes when something works fine on localhost but not own other sever is also because of short tags. If you have enabled short tags on local server but not on other server, you are bound to receive error or un-expected output. So check with matching of short tags also.